# Unable mock an enumerable result from a task

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I want to mock the UniteofWork.FileApproveOverrideRepo.GetAllOverrideApprovals method 
Everything working based on the code below just mylist is empty.

```
public async Task<List<FileApprovalOverrideResponse>> GetAllOverrideApprovals(int cpId)
    {
        var overrideApprovals = await UnitOfWork.FileApprovalOverrideRepository.Get(t => t.CPId == cpId, null, t => t.ActionedByUser.Company);

        var mylist = overrideApprovals.ToList(); 

        return MapperInstance.Map<List<FileApprovalOverrideResponse>>(mylist);
    }
```

And here is how I mock my method :

```
    var mockedUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
                var mockedGenericRepoCPApproval = new Mock<IGenericAsyncRepository<FileApprovalOverride>>();
                var listOfFileApprovalOverrride = new FileApprovalOverride[] {

                    new FileApprovalOverride()
                {
                    FileApprovalOverrideId = 2,
                    FileId = 2,
                    CPId = 2,
                    ApprovalStatus = 3,
                    IntendedApproverType = (byte)approvType,
                    IsValid = true,
                    Reason = ""
                    },
                    new FileApprovalOverride()
                    {
                    FileApprovalOverrideId = 2,
                    FileId = 2,
                    CPId = 2,
                    ApprovalStatus = 3,
                    IntendedApproverType = (byte)approvType,
                    IsValid = true,
                    Reason = "",
                    }
                };

                 var myenumerable = listOfFileApprovalOverrride;               
                mockedGenericRepoCPApproval.Setup(_ => _.Get(t => t.CPId == 1, null, t => t.ActionedByUser.Company)).ReturnsAsync(myenumerable);
                mockedUnitOfWork.Setup(_ => _.FileApprovalOverrideRepository).Returns(mockedGenericRepoCPApproval.Object);
var cpApprovalService = new CpApprovalService(mockCPApprovalRepository.Object, new Mock<ICPRepository>().Object, new Mock<ICPService>().Object, new Mock<ICompanyRepository>().Object, new Mock<ICPLinkedCompanyService>().Object, new Mock<ICPExportService>().Object, new Mock<IEmailService>().Object, new Mock<ICPContactService>().Object, new Mock<ISystemUserRespository>().Object, new Mock<IUserManagementService>().Object, new Mock<IAuditLogService>().Object, new Mock<ISignCharterParty>().Object, new Mock<IEmailQueuer>().Object);

            cpApprovalService.UnitOfWork = mockedUnitOfWork.Object;
            cpApprovalService.MapperInstance = mapperInstanse;

            return cpApprovalService;
```

I put a break point where I am creating the mock even there the *myenumerable* is correct and it has two members but when I run the test then the mylist is empty.

Comment: You passing a reference type to `.Get(t => t.CPId == cpId, null, t => t.ActionedByUser.Company);`. It will return your enumerable only when it is get same reference of predicate.

Comment: you are right thanks. You can post that one as an answer if you like.